Gracefully terminate tkinter app (including multithreading, multiprocessing, QueueHandler, QueueListener)
Question
How to make a python tkinter app close gracefully at the end of normal operation and if user terminates the window interrupting the processing being performed?
Details
The tkinter app launches a long running function long.work() on click of a button, this function is started in a new thread which allows the tkinter app to be responsive during the long execution.
Some of the functions called in work() are multithreaded via ThreadPoolExecutor (concurrent_tasks.do_multi_threads()), and others are multiprocessed via joblib Parallel() and delayed() (parallel_tasks.do_multi_process()).
Therefore, graceful ending must handle cases where no user termination occurs, user termination occurs after function completes, user interruption occurs in the multithreadeded and multiprocess states, as well as handle closing of loggers that use QueueListener and QueueHandler to write log messages to a log file.
I have looked at some similar questions here on SO, but none cover all of the use cases required.
Example
My approach so far gives error when closing window interrupting the multithreaded function (among others):
app.py
import logging
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler, QueueListener
import sys
import multiprocessing
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, ttk
from joblib.externals.loky import get_reusable_executor

import long


def finish(
    logger: logging.Logger,
    listener: QueueListener = None,
    log_queue: multiprocessing.Queue = None,
    threads: bool = False,
    lock: threading.Lock = None,
    root: tk.Tk = None,
    exit_code: int = 0,
):
    # QueueHandler
    if log_queue is not None:
        log_queue.put_nowait(None)

    # QueueListener
    if listener is not None:
        listener.stop()

    # joblib
    get_reusable_executor(kill_workers=True).shutdown(wait=True)

    # multiprocessing
    for p in multiprocessing.active_children():
        p.terminate()
        p.join()

    # threading
    if threads is True:
        for thread in threading.enumerate():
            if thread is not threading.current_thread():
                thread.join(timeout=1)

    # logger
    for handler in logger.handlers:
        handler.flush()
        handler.close()
    logger.handlers.clear()

    # lock
    if lock is not None and lock.locked():
        lock.release()

    # tkinter
    if root is not None:
        root.destroy()
        sys.exit(exit_code)


def main():
    root = Tk()

    # logger
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_fmt = logging.Formatter(
        "%(asctime)s (%(levelname)s) %(message)s", datefmt="%H:%M:%S"
    )
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler("log_file.log")
    file_handler.setFormatter(log_fmt)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    
    # note also a StreamHandler is added to QueueListener

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    log_queue = manager.Queue()
    queue_handler = QueueHandler(log_queue)
    logger.addHandler(queue_handler)

    listener = QueueListener(log_queue, file_handler, respect_handler_level=True)
    listener.start()

    def begin():
        # entry_vals = get Entry values...
        exit_code = 0
        lock = threading.Lock()

        def terminate():
            finish(logger, listener, log_queue, threads=True, lock=lock, root=root, exit_code=exit_code)
        
        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", terminate)

        def start():  # EDIT
            try:
                long.work(entry_vals)
            finally:
                button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)  # re-enable
                finish(logger, listener, log_queue, threads=True, lock=lock, root=None, exit_code=exit_code)

        try:  # EDIT (indentation)
            set_progress = entry_vals.get("update_status")
            if set_progress:  # EDIT
                set_progress("begin", 1)  # EDIT
            logging. Debug("Starting GUI...")
            button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)  # disable button
            threading.Thread(target=start).start()  # EDIT
        except Exception as e:
            exit_code = 1
            logging.exception(e)
            finish(logger, listener, log_queue, threads=False, lock=None, root=None, exit_code=exit_code)

    frame = ttk.Frame(root)
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)
    button = ttk.Button(frame, text="Start", command=begin)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

long.py
import logging
from concurrent. Futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

import concurrent_tasks
import parallel_tasks

def work(entry_vals):
    set_progress = entry_vals.get("update_status")
    partial_func = partial(concurrent_tasks.do_multi_threads, entry_vals)
    if set_progress:  # EDIT
        set_progress("work", 10)  # EDIT
    logging.debug("Starting multithreaded function...")  # EDIT
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        res_1 = list(executor.map(partial_func, range(10)))
    
    if set_progress:  # EDIT
        set_progress("work", 60)  # EDIT
    logging.debug("Starting multiprocessed function...")  # EDIT
    with Parallel(n_jobs=-1) as parallel_work:
        res_2 = list(parallel_work(delayed(parallel_tasks.do_multi_process)(entry_vals, i) for i in range(10)))

    return res_1, res_2

Additional info
This edit adds to the oversimplified code representation above: There is some functional programming that allows incrementation of a tk.ttk.Progressbar via setting a tk.IntVar which is the argument for the Progressbar parameter variable.
app.py
def update_status(
    progress_var,
    progress_bar,
    percent_label,
    status_label,
    lock
):
    def callback(section, percent):
        with lock:
            if percent is not None:
                progress_var.set(percent)
            percent_label["text"] = f"{progress_var.get()}%"
            status_label["text"] = section

            progress_bar.update_idletasks()
            percent_label.update_idletasks()
            status_label.update_idletasks()

        progress_bar.after(10000, callback)
    return callback

Error
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
main thread is not in main loop

in start:
long.work(entry_vals)

in work:
set_progress("work", 60)

in callback:
progress_var.set(percent)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
in start:
button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop


Which error? Post the full traceback. Error related to Tkinter or error related to imported package/modules?

@8349697 Apologies, I oversimplified the code; I have now added the additional info and made edits to the original code (annotated).

There are some approaches suggested in the tkdocs. This answer shows a simple example of using event_generate.

The answer suggested states that it will return error if the application is closed before the background thread completes, which is what I am trying to avoid so it doesn't solve my problem. Elements from the docs suggested I am already using.

The error occurs in the start function. Try adding an event to the threading.Thread(target=start). So you can set a stop flag for that thread in the def finish.
